# Image distortion with sine with bilinear interpolation c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, distortion

I'm trying to do an distortion with sine/cosine with Bilinear interpolation with the next code, I'm keeping the same size of the new image as the old image . And the results doesn't look good.

```
Mat biliniar(Mat old, int freq){
namedWindow( "car2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
imshow( "car2", old); 
int height = old.size().height;
int width = old.size().width;

unsigned char R1,R2,R3,R4;     // Colours at the four neighbours
unsigned char G1,G2,G3,G4;
unsigned char B1,B2,B3,B4;
double RT1, GT1, BT1;          // Interpolated colours at T1 and T2
double RT2, GT2, BT2;
unsigned char R,G,B;           // Final colour at a destination pixel
unsigned char *dst;            // Destination image - must be allocated here! 
int x,y;               // Coordinates on destination image
double fi,fj;              // Corresponding coordinates on source image

Mat res(height,width,CV_8UC3,cv::Scalar(100));
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        fi = i;
        fj =  (j - (((height/30)*(sin((M_PI*i)/(freq/2)))))) + sqrt(height) ; 
        //cout << fj << " ";
        if(fj > 0 &  fj < height){
            //cout << " p1: x:" << floor(fi) << " y:" << floor(fj);
            //cout << " p2: x:" << ceil(fi) << " y:" << floor(fj);
            //cout << " p3: x:" << floor(fi) << " y:" << ceil(fj);
            //cout << " p4: x:" << ceil(fi) << " y:" << ceil(fj);
            Vec3b color1 = old.at<Vec3b>(Point(floor(fi)-1,floor(fj)));
            R1 = color1.val[0]; G1 = color1.val[1]; B1 = color1.val[2];
            Vec3b color2 = old.at<Vec3b>(Point(ceil(fi)+1,floor(fj)));
            R2 = color2.val[0]; G2 = color2.val[1]; B2 = color2.val[2];
            Vec3b color3 = old.at<Vec3b>(Point(floor(fi)-1,ceil(fj)));
            R3 = color3.val[0]; G3 = color3.val[1]; B3 = color3.val[2];
            Vec3b color4 = old.at<Vec3b>(Point(ceil(fi)+1,ceil(fj)));
            R4 = color4.val[0]; G4 = color4.val[1]; B4 = color4.val[2];
            RT1 = (R1+R2)/2; GT1 = (G1+G2)/2; BT1 = (B1+B2)/2;
            RT2 = (R3+R4)/2; GT2 = (G3+G4)/2; BT2 = (B3+B4)/2;
            R=(unsigned char)(RT1+RT2);
            G=(unsigned char)(GT1+GT2);
            B=(unsigned char)(BT1+BT2);
            Vec3b finalColor(R,G,B);
            res.at<Vec3b>(j,i) = finalColor;
        }
    }
}
namedWindow( "bilinear", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
imshow( "bilinear", res); 
return res;
```

}

The results of the nearest neighbor interpolation came out mach better, Any body has an idea why?

Thanks

Comment: post images for input and your outputs (if applicable), please

Comment: I cant because I'm new on stackoverflaw and my reputation is not high enough.

Comment: one thing: `R1 = color1.val[0]` is probably not read color but blue color, but since you do the same error again in `Vec3b finalColor(R,G,B);` it should be no problem.

Comment: Did it now. it didn't change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually doing any bilinear interpolation in that code, you're just adding all the four pixels together.

You need to compute the fractional parts of fi and fj and use them to perform the interpolation, e.g:

```
double fi_part = fi - floor(fi);
double fj_part = fj - floor(fj);

// perform interpolation in i direction:
RT1 = (R1*(1.0-fi_part)) + (R2*fi_part);
GT1 = (G1*(1.0-fi_part)) + (G2*fi_part);
BT1 = (B1*(1.0-fi_part)) + (B2*fi_part);
RT2 = (R3*(1.0-fi_part)) + (R4*fi_part);
GT2 = (G3*(1.0-fi_part)) + (G4*fi_part);
BT2 = (B3*(1.0-fi_part)) + (B4*fi_part);

// perform interpolation in j direction:
R=(unsigned char)(RT1*(1.0-fj_part)+RT2*fj_part);
G=(unsigned char)(GT1*(1.0-fj_part)+GT2*fj_part);
B=(unsigned char)(BT1*(1.0-fj_part)+BT2*fj_part);

Vec3b finalColor(R,G,B);
res.at<Vec3b>(j,i) = finalColor;
```

So, as fi_part increases from 0.0 to 1.0 as you move across one texel, less and less of R1,G1,B1 and more and more of R2,G2,B2 will contribute to RT1,GT1,BT1. Likewise for RT2 etc and similarly for the calculations involving fj_part.

Code could be improved a lot for speed, but hopefully you get the basic idea.